# Split extension of linear algebraic groups given by unipotent radicals and reductive groups

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, schemes, group-schemes

I've read that there is a split extension of any linear algebraic group $G$ over a perfect field given by
$$ 1 \to R_u(G) \to G  \to H \to 1$$
where $R_u(G)$ is the radical unipotent subgroup of $G$ and $H$ is a reductive group, but I can't figure out what the section map is, explicitly.

So

> In the above split sequence, what does the section $H \to G$ do, exactly?

Comment: "the" section map is not unique...